# Looking for Low Noise High Shielding BNC

Tags: connector, low-voltage, bnc, research

I am doing some research looking at low voltage signals, on the order of 100nV. Due to the usage of other equipment such as a current source there is spurious pickup noise in the cables carrying this low voltage signal. I am looking for a BNC cable with low noise to carry this signal — additionally if there are cables with additional shielding to block other signals in the cables around it that would be ideal. The signal needs to travel at most 7 feet and the frequency of the signal is less than 100 kHz.

Are there any cables out there that meet these requirements? What specs should I look for when searching for the cables?

Comment: not BNC. That's why TNC (Threaded BNC) and N-type (Navy connector, the inner is electrically same as BNC) were invented.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use BNC for such signals because it's unbalanced.

Use a connector that supports a balanced line instead. A balance line lets you subtract out the common-mode noise.

If you do want to use a coax-type connector, consider [twinax connectors](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=twinax_conn) (my site): BNC twinax, TNC twinax, TE Coaxicon.

Or, switch to circular connectors. For example, an [XLR connector](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=std_xlr_circular_conn&s=XLR) (my site). They make low-noise XLR cables for microphones (there is an additional carbon shield).

But the best advice I can give you is: don't. Instead of carrying 100 nV through a cable, install a low noise amplifier at the signal source, and then carry the amplified signal in a cable.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I use 2 BNC in differential mode so only center conductors carry the signal. They also go through a 100x preamplifier before going to a lock in amplifier with 100dB CMN rejection filter. Any additional advice?

Comment: Running the two lines in the same cable is better because it lets you remove the common mode noise. If you use two cables, they pick-up different levels of noise, so you can't subtract it out. Which is why I suggested a twinax connector.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot of luck with RG393 double shielded coaxial cables. They're easily workable with the correct tools and offer a highly flexible low-noise solution.

```
https://www.pasternack.com/images/ProductPDF/RG393-U-BULK.pdf
https://www.pasternack.com/bnc-male-standard-rg214-rg9-rg225-rg393-connector-pe4351-p.aspx
```

A TNC can also be used for a threaded connection (better shield contact). But either way, make sure you use an HX4 or equivalent to crimp the ferrule and solder the center conductor with a quality leaded solder. Make sure there's no flux when you're done.

[image: RG393 W/BNC & UHF Terminations]

Comment: You might need to consider what type of dielectric the coax has as some materials are piezoelectric. Teflon might be the better choice.

Comment: Both items recommended have a PTFE (Teflon) dielectric.